# In J2ME app, is that possible to set alarm's ringtone as MP3 tone?

Tags: java-me, ringtone

In J2ME app, I want to give freedom to user to set his/her own liking tone though it is .mp3 or .wav sound with high bit rate & size. It is possible in J2ME with `javax.microedition.media` package??

I tried to do this with one .wav file whose size is 2.52MB and bit rate is 352kpbs but Netbeans showed me exception which is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayAccessor.commandAction(Display.java:1996)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayManagerImpl.commandAction(Display.java:2825)
    at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DefaultEventHandler.commandEvent(DefaultEventHandler.java:303)
    at com.sun.midp.lcdui.AutomatedEventHandler.commandEvent(AutomatedEventHandler.java:670)
    at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DefaultEventHandler$QueuedEventHandler.handleVmEvent(+186)
    at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DefaultEventHandler$QueuedEventHandler.run(+57)
```

So is there any way to do this or I have to restrict user to use tones which is provided with app?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the ringtone or alarm tone of the device via JavaME.

You can make an app that plays its own tone. Which formats can be played depends on the device. And how big they can be, depends on the amount of memory available on the device.

If you wish for your app to be compatible with the most possible devices, you should use MIDI or AMR files. All newer devices do also support mp3 and wav files though, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok..... but if i used smaller size or(compressed) mp3 format tone then it will possible??

Comment: It will always depend on how much memory is available on the specific device. It may work on one device but not the other. And of course also depend on whether that specific device supports mp3 files or not.